# Program developed on SP2010 work for 2013?

Tags: 2010, 2013, sharepoint-enterprise

I have a program which was developed on SP2010. It refers SharePoint dll in a c# console program to get SPWeb info, then get some library info.

Now, I need to make it work in SP2013. When I run it, it shows this error:

```
could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library, Version=14.0.0.0, culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or one of its dependencies
```

Is there a way to get around this? Or, we have to compile it in a SP2013 environment? The previous developer did not leave the source code, so we try to see whether we can get around of recompiling it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, you will need to get into the code to upgrade it. There will be references in it to version 14, as you have above. This refers to 2010. You will need to change them to 15 for 2013.